# Using For Each Loop to Programmatically Generate Shapes and Add Macros

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, I'm in a bit over my head with this one, but I'm hoping that the answer is much simpler than it seems from my limited perspective.

I have an Excel workbook that I'm trying to set up as a Macro-enabled Template, and so I need all of my code and formulas to be extremely flexible, since they'll need to adapt dynamically to the project they're being used for in each instance.

Sheet 1 will be the Splice_Diagram sheet, and I have a named range on this sheet with the following reference:

`=Splice_Diagram!$R$3:INDEX(Splice_Diagram!$R:$R,MATCH("",Splice_Diagram!$R:$R,-1))`

The number of sheets named in this range will be variable based on the number of splices the project requires.

I need to create a macro to iterate through this list, create a shape for each, and assign the following to each shape:

```
Sheets("[Name of Sheet indicated in List]").Select
Range("A3").Select
```

The individual phases of this, I'm more or less able to muddle through, but I'm having trouble passing the names of the sheets iterated through in the Loop to the Macro Sheets.Select command.

For instance, if there are three Splices, then the list on the Splice_Diagram page will be Splice_01, Splice_02, and Splice_03. This should result in three shapes with Text that says Splice_01, Splice_02, and Splice_03 respectively. These shapes should run:

Splice_01:

```
Sheets("Splice_01").Select
Range("A3").Select
```

Splice_02:

```
Sheets("Splice_02").Select
Range("A3").Select
```

Splice_03:

```
Sheets("Splice_03").Select
Range("A3").Select
```

The sheets will always be labeled with the Prefix "Splice_" and an incrementing number, if that helps. However, the number of Splices will always be different.

The locations of the shapes don't matter at all, even if they're all stacked on top of each other, because I'll need to move them around to simulate the network anyway.

For the creation of the shapes themselves, I'm just using this little piece currently:

```
SpliceGuide.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 200
```

I hope this was clear, please let me know if there's something incredibly obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include more of the code? The 2 lines included aren't enough to give more than the most general suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to assign the name of a sheet to each shape? Like changing the name of the shape to the name of the sheet? 
And if so, what you you mean by "passing the values from the Loop to the Sheet Names". Are you changing the sheet names?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I edited my post to add a little clarity, but definitely let me know if I'm still not being clear enough.

Comment: You need some way of dynamically determining how many splices are on your `Splice_Diagram` worksheet (might be as simple as just reading the values in the relevant range). Once you know that, you can loop over each solice -- and stick the code that you use to create each shape (plus text) inside that loop. You might need to change parts of the loop to refer to the current iteration/splice being looped over.

Comment: Do you want the shape text to be the value from "A3" from the corresponding sheet? If you wouldn't mind, an image with an example would be helpful.